# Why are $g^{-1} k_i g = k_i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Let $\mathcal{K} = \{k_1, \dots , k_m\}$ be a conjugacy class in the finite group $G.$

$(a)$ Prove that the element $K = k_1 + \dots + k_m$ is in the center of the group ring $RG.$ [Check that $g^{-1} K g = K \text{ for all} g \in G.$]

My question is:

In the following solution (which can be found in the following link https://linearalgebras.com/solution-abstract-algebra-exercise-7-2-13.html ):

> [image]

Why are $g^{-1} k_i g = k_i$? should not the conjugation be between two different elements as defined here https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/conjclass.pdf

In this pdf, tt said that in a group G, two elements g and h are called conjugate when
$$h = xgx^{−1}$$ for some $x\in G$.

Could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody is claiming that $g^{-1}k_ig=k_i$ for each index $i$. What is being claimed is that$$\sum_{i=1}^ng^{-1}k_ig=\sum_{i=1}^nk_i,$$which is clear, since the map $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$ permutes the elements of $\mathcal K$. Therefore, the sets $\{k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n\}$ and $\{g^{-1}k_1g,g^{-1}k_2g,\ldots,g^{-1}k_ng\}$ are identical.

Comment: What do you mean by permutes the elements of $\mathcal K$ then?

Comment: Is that what you meant by conjugation by $g$ permutes the elelments of $\mathcal K$ i.e., $k_i = g^{-1} k_j g$ for some $g \in G$ and for $1 \leq i,j \leq m$ and we eventually get the same sum again?

Comment: Is it correct saying that $\mathcal K$ an element of the group ring at the beginning of the solution or it should be $K$ instead?

Comment: I am saying that, for each $g$, the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathcal K&\longrightarrow&\mathcal K\\k&\mapsto&g^{-1}kg\end{array}$$is a bijection. Therefore, the sum of all elements $k\in\mathcal K$ is the sum of all elements of the form $g^{-1}kg$ ($k\in\mathcal K$), since we are summing the *same* elements.